# How to determine the concrete type of an injected property?

Tags: typescript, oop

I've encounteded this common issue in my code, though it feels right, something seems off about it and I lack the experience to determine if this is the correct way of going about it. Essentially I have a class that implementes an interfaces. Some of these properties within this interface require an injection from another interface and is where the troubles occur. For example:

```
export abstract class Session<TConfig extends object, TData extends object> implements ISession<TConfig, TData>{

    public extension: IExtension<TConfig, TData>;

    public role?: PartnerUserRoleEnum | undefined;

    public session: ISessionProperties<TConfig, TData>;


    constructor(extension: IExtension<TConfig, TData>, data: ISessionAuthProperties<TConfig, TData>){
        this.extension = extension;
        
        this.session = data.session;
        
        this.role = data.role;
        
    }
}
```

Because this is an abstract class, I must inherit `Session` as a parent class. In doing so I unintentionally omit the actual concrete definition type I pass in.

```
export class RandomEventSession extends Session<RandomEventConfig, RandomEventData>{

    constructor(session: ISessionAuthProperties<RandomEventConfig, RandomEventData> ){

        super(RandomEventExtension.Singleton, session)
    
    }

    async TriggerRandomEvent(){

    }

    async TriggerEvent(){

    }
}
```

In the above example, if I was to access `extension` using the concrete class `RandomEventExtension` I "wouldnt" be able to access the methods and properties unique to `RandomEventExtension`.

I could just implement `ISession` into `RandomEventSession` however, if I decided to add a complex function into `Session`, I'd have to re-write that same function again. This leads me to believe the way I have done it is, not wrong, but not the best approach. If it was possible to somehow say "the type of `extension` passed into `session` will be the type of `session.extension`" then things would work correctly but I dont know if this is possible. Any pointers?

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to start working on your issue without having to resolve unrelated issues (like missing declarations).

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when trying to use generics that shouldnt be apart of the specific abstraction, rather than using `TConfig` and `TData` to construct `ISessionProperties` and `IExtension`, we instead pass `ISessionProperties` and `IExtension` explicitly. As a result we get a slighlty modified version:

```
export abstract class Session<
    TSession extends ISessionProperties<object, object>, 
    TExtension extends IExtension<TSession>
> implements ISession<TSession, TExtension>{

    public extension: TExtension;

    public role?: PartnerUserRoleEnum | undefined;

    public session: TSession;
    
    public lockForUser?: LockForPublic | undefined;

    public userId?: string | undefined;

    constructor(extension: TExtension, data: ISessionAuthProperties<TSession>){
        this.extension = extension;
        
        this.session = data.session;

        this.lockForUser = data.lockForUser;
        
        this.role = data.role;
        
        this.userId = data.userId;
    }
}
```

This example is quite specific to my use-case, however, if you encounter similar problems, a rule of thumb is, if youre using an interface as a type, it is very difficult to retrieve the concrete implementation of that property and so should be avoided unless that class only needs the properties and methods within the interface.